# What is hint in the openGauss?

Tags: sql, database, optimization, hint

It seems that there are so many hints used in the openGauss, any one know the basic design idea of the hint in openGauss?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a better performance for a certain query, using hints is a method to adjust the query plan while the optimizer not choose a correct plan for one query.
For example, you can change the join order, or change the join return row number for a certain query to improve performance.
you can learn hints on this page
https://opengauss.org/en/docs/2.1.0/docs/Developerguide/hint-based-tuning.html